# If equation is not expectation

Tags: autohotkey

I am new to Auto Hotkey .  I am testing IF statement.  It's telling me that 5 is not greater than 3.  Not sure what's wrong.

```
vSec := 5
vSec1 := 3
if vSec > vSec1
    msgbox larger `r`n  %vSec% `r`n %vSec1%
else
    msgbox vSec:%vSec% less or equal to vSec1:%vSec1%
```

[image]

Comment: What did you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the [old If syntax](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/IfEqual.htm), in which the right-hand side of the expression is treated as a string. To make it a variable, you would need to add `%`s:

```
vSec := 5
vSec1 := 3
if vSec > %vSec1%
    msgbox larger `r`n  %vSec% `r`n %vSec1%
else
    msgbox vSec:%vSec% less or equal to vSec1:%vSec1%
```

Or use the newer syntax:

```
vSec := 5
vSec1 := 3
if (vSec > vSec1)
    msgbox larger `r`n  %vSec% `r`n %vSec1%
else
    msgbox vSec:%vSec% less or equal to vSec1:%vSec1%
```